# Spacewalk some packages not being sync'd

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

I am trying to troubleshoot why packages would not clone.

As an example, the latest tzdata package, currently it is only in my official mirror channel:

```
[root@pro-adm9000 ~]# spacewalk-report channel-packages | grep tzdata-2015[fg] | grep centos
centos7-x86_64-updates,CentOS 7 Updates (x86_64),tzdata,2015f,1.el7,,noarch,tzdata-2015f-1.el7.noarch
centos7-x86_64-updates,CentOS 7 Updates (x86_64),tzdata,2015g,1.el7,,noarch,tzdata-2015g-1.el7.noarch
pit-centos7-x86_64-updates,Point In Time Centos 7 x86_64 Updates,tzdata,2015f,1.el7,,noarch,tzdata-2015f-1.el7.noarch
```

So version g exists in the official mirror channel, but not the point in time channel.

I tried doing a manual sync in case my conf file was incorrect:
`[root@pro-adm9000 scripts]# spacewalk-clone-by-date --username admin --channels=centos7-x86_64-updates pit-centos7-x86_64-updates --to_date 2015-12-11 -a centos7-x86_64 pit-centos7-x86_64`

Gave it 24 hours after verifying taskomatic is running, but still only 2015f available in my cloned channel (pit-centos7-x86_64-updates)

I've gone down the fsck route as well to ensure no data issues exist
`spacewalk-data-fsck -v -r -R`

The original snippet for cloning is as follow:

```
      "centos7-x86_64-updates": {
        "label": "pit-centos7-x86_64-updates",
        "name": "Point In Time Centos 7 x86_64 Updates",
        "summary": "Point In Time Updates Summary",
        "description": "Point In Time Updates Desc",
        "parent": "pit-centos7-x86_64"
       },
```

With the following defaults:

```
{
"username":"admin",
"password":"XXXXXX",
"assumeyes":true,
"skip_depsolve":false,
"security_only":false,
"use_update_date":false,
"no_errata_sync":false,
"dry_run":false,
"blacklist": {"ALL":["cglib-*"]
             },
```

I know the repodata is being rebuilt by taskomatic:
`INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/12/09 10:25:52 | 2015-12-09 10:25:52,390 [Thread-53] INFO  com.redhat.rhn.taskomatic.task.repomd.RepositoryWriter - Repository metadata generation for 'pit-centos7-x86_64-updates' finished in 33 seconds`